# Navigate through nested classes and set values using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I'm trying to build a UI which allows me to take a class of an unknown definition type (there will be a library of defined classes but they could have any structure and the code needs to deal with all of them generically), build input fields for population and then save the input fields back into the object.

An example object is something like this:

```
// This is the class which will be pulled apart and put back together with the new values...
public class Level1()
{
public Level1() {}
public Level2 Level2NestedClass1 {get;set;}
public Level2 Level2NestedClass2 {get;set;}
public string SomeText {get;set;}
}

// This class is nested within Level1
public class Level2()
{
public Level2() {}
public Level3 Level3NestedClass {get;set;}
public bool SomeBool {get;set;}
}

// This class is nested within Level2
public class Level3()
{
public Level3() {}
public string SomeMoreText {get;set;}
}
```

I've managed to get as far as creating input fields and saving the values for any properties on `Level1` and any properties on `Level2`, but I can't get any further down the chain than that. Ideally it would need to be arbitrarily extensible.

The issue I'm having is I can't find a way to get to the nested properties and set the values on my "parent" class (`Level1`) because they are actually stored on `Level2`. e.g.

```
// This gets me the value of Level2 on Level1 so that I can set it
level1.GetType().GetProperty(level2.Name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)?.GetValue(level1)
```

I can't work out how to pull Level2 off of Level1, so that I could use this to then recursively loop up to the top level and set the objects as I go, e.g. set all values on `Level3` then set `Level3` on `Level2` and then `Level2` on `Level1` so that the full nested hierarchy of values is maintained on the object at the end.

If I use `Activator.CreateInstance` to get the instance of `Level2` I will lose all prior values I've set and only the last item set is saved. e.g.

```
var level2 = Activator.CreateInstance(level3.DeclaringType);

// This gets me the value of Level3 on Level2 so that I can set it
level2.GetType().GetProperty(level3.Name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)?.GetValue(level2)
```

Any tips or packages that might help would be appreciated. I've had a look all over google and stackoverflow but every example I've found uses known definitions and breadcrumb style lookups e.g. Level1.Level2.Level3 whereas I do not know the definition until runtime - I guess I could add attributes to the classes to define the breadcrumbs and use those?

Comment: Is your question about the reflection part (if so, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48701826/9239792)) or is it on the dynamic generation of an UI?

Comment: You are trying to pass values from UI? Maybe if you create an class, like a view model, with simple unique properties, and use AutoMapper to map your view model class to your complex types, is an option.

Comment: The question is about reflection - I can't set the properties on the nested classes and end up with my Level1 class that has all nested classes and nested properties set on it.

Comment: @RMH I have looked at your answer and I think it may have helped. I'm looping over each of my input fields individually but I have already stored the "parent" on each of them - perhaps I need to create the object, set all of its values and then just append that to the parent object - I will try this. I'm still not entirely sure how to get further than one level down though.

Comment: @DannyLager [here is fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gimpfq) with the example of 3 levels. Or do you mean, how to (re) create the objects based off your input values? For that the breadcrumbs will work, you can use the property names as the crumbs (that is basically how ASP MVC does it).

Comment: @RMH Thanks for the example. Yeah I am trying to recreate the top level object (Level1) with all sub properties set with the values from my UI input fields. So I need a Level1 object with all nested classes and values populated at the end. I've used reflection to create an instance of the object and pull the relevant values out and onto the UI, now I am trying to pull them out of the UI and put them back into the object - simple if I knew what the object was, but I don't... that's what makes it fun!

Comment: @DannyLager Maybe if you show us how you are trying to get values from UI, be helpful to understand the problem.

Comment: Unless you expect to be dealing with unknown and unpredictable types, what you're trying to do generally doesn't pay off. You will go down a rabbit-hole of one-offs, like what happens when a property is an array or a dictionary. Even though it sounds like more work and less reuse you're usually better off just dealing with it one class at a time. (By usually I mean almost always.) Depending on what your end goal is there are numerous libraries and nuget packages which can probably streamline the process for you.